# How to wait for jQuery animation?

Tags: jquery, ajax, animation

i know that such a question has been asked thousand times, but i didn't find a solution for me.

I have a function, that is called when a form is submitted. It checks some form fields and send the data with ajax to a php script. The problem is, that it can need some seconds until php is finished and i wanted to fade in a css animation, that the user knows that he shall wait.

If there is an error in a form field, the animation is correctly faded in and out. But if the fields check is ok, mostly jQuery goes on and calls ajax without finishing the animation. Sometimes the animation is faded in, sometimes it stops after a few milliseconds and sometimes nothing happens until the answer from the php script comes back.

How can i tell jquery to wait with the execution of the ajax part until the animation is finished?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.daten_form').submit(function () {
        $("#loader-wrapper").fadeIn('normal');
        hasError = false;
        if ($('#delkfz').prop('checked',false)){
            if ($('#fin').val() == '') {
                $('#fin').addClass('error_class');
                hasError = true;
            }
        }
        if (hasError) {
            $("#loader-wrapper").fadeOut("normal");
            $('.error_box').show();
        } else {
            var einzelfz = false;
            var weiter = false;
            if ($('#einzelfz').val() == '1')
                einzelfz = true;
            if ($("#weiter").prop('checked') == true)
                weiter = true;
            var kvid = $('#kvid').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'kvc_write.php',
                cache: false,
                data: $(".daten_form").serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data == "error") {
                        $("#loader-wrapper").fadeOut("normal");
                        $('.success_box').hide();
                        $('.error_box').show();
                    } else if (data == "logout") {
                        var url = "index.php?ablauf=1";
                        $(location).attr('href',url);
                    } else if (data == "success" && (einzelfz || !weiter)) {
                        var url = "prepkvpdf.php?kvid="+kvid;
                        $(location).attr('href',url);
                    } else {
                        $("#loader-wrapper").fadeOut("normal");
                        $('.error_box').hide();
                        $('.success_box').show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: This code is not complete! where is the callback function. What are you doing when the ajax is done?

Comment: Please read [the documentation for `fadeIn`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and note the `complete` function you can pass in.

Comment: just a nitpick, but you dont have to write `== true`, you can just assert the variable, ie.  `if(hasError)`

Comment: I shortened the script as much as possible (fields checking, ajax, ...) coz that is working fine and doesn't matter here.

Comment: call the ajax function as a callback of the animation function. It will be started after the animation is completed

Comment: Just tried a simple function with an alert for the `complete`. Its executed before the fadeIn is finished.

Comment: `$("#loader-wrapper").fadeIn('normal', function() { if (hasError) { $(".. } });`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use a Ajax:

```
        $.ajax({
            data: data,
            type: "GET", //or POST
            url: "YOU-KNOW.php",
            beforeSend: function(){
                //script runs when ajax send data
            },      
            success: function(data){
                //script runs when php finish the thing and tell me data.
            }
        });
```

Comment: I just tried that, but still the same. Sometimes the animation is faded in for 10%, sometimes nothing is to see.

Comment: I upgraded the code now. Just the part where the form fields are checked is shortened. This is the original code as it was yesterday morning. All I tried after that didn't work. Either there were no changes or this `$("#loader-wrapper").fadeIn('normal', function() { if (hasError) { $(".. } });` didn't work over all but without an error on the console?!

Comment: What is exatly the problem?

Comment: When the function is called, the `#loader-wrapper` shall be faded in before anything else is started. If hasError is set to true, it is faded in completely and then faded out again. Absolutely correct. But if the else part is called, sometimes the fadeIn works, but mostly it either stops after about 10% or no effect is visible. As i meanwhile found out, the problem is probably the jQuery cache, coz it works fine for a few times after changing from jQuery 1.x to 3.2.0. But as the php part needs several seconds to finish, it doesn't matter if the user waits half a second longer or not.

Comment: I dont know how to help. The success part must run when php is finished, so, the animate problem must be something else. Can you make a fiddle or something for testing online?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I tried several options to export the "working problem", but no success.